# How to use urllib in python?

Tags: python, urllib

I was wondering if somebody can help me with getting my code to work.

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import re

url = 'https://www.google.com'
values = {'s':'basics',
      'submit':'search'}
data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
data = data.encode('utf-8')
req = urllib.request.Request(url,data)
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
respData = resp.read()

print(respData)
```

It is giving me this error message when running the code.

```
TypeError: POST data should be bytes, an iterable of bytes, or a file object. It cannot be of type str.
```

I hope someone can help me with my problem. If not thanks anyways.

It is giving me this gigantic error message:

```
It is giving me this gigantic error    
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\Lotto.py", line 11, in <module>
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib   \request.py", line 222, in urlopen
return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 531, in open
response = meth(req, response)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 641, in http_response
'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 569, in error
return self._call_chain(*args)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 405: Method Not Allowed
```

Comment: Note that the official documentation recommends using the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library.

Comment: You hace a typo. It says `date = data.encode('utf-8')`

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because you have a TYPO:

```
data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
date = data.encode('utf-8') # YOUR TYPO IS HERE
req = urllib.request.Request(url,data)
```

You need to change that line to:

```
data = data.encode('utf-8') # TYPO FIXED!
```

Comment: My error is in line 11. Something is wrong there, but I don't know what.